# SPARQL - Get entity type from a String

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, wikidata

I'm using Wikidata with the purpose to find, for the String "Scotland", the values of the properties "type / instance of", "subclass of" and "part of" if they exist.

For example, manually by browsing the Wikidata's website, I type Scotland, I find the ressource and those data are displayed inside it, just like : https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22. Thus I can see that Scotland is an instance of "country within the United Kingdom".

What would be the equivalent query in SPARQL to do that please ?

I tried this "valid" query but it whether does not return any results or bypasses the time limit :

```
SELECT ?instanceOf ?subclassOf ?partOf WHERE {
  ?word rdfs:label ?label;
       wdt:P361 ?instanceOf;
       wdt:P279 ?subclassOf;
       wdt:P361 ?partOf.
  FILTER(CONTAINS(?label, "Scotland"))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FinstanceOf%20%3FsubclassOf%20%3FpartOf%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fword%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP361%20%3FinstanceOf%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP279%20%3FsubclassOf%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP361%20%3FpartOf.%0A%20%20FILTER%28CONTAINS%28%3Flabel%2C%20%22Scotland%22%29%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: 1. The Filter on Label, like this, is the cause of TimeLimit, it is a real heavy request. 2. Are you sure that the relations exist? Q22 rdfs:subClassOf is not for example.

Comment: Without a fulltext index, those kind of queries are usually to expensive...Wikidata doesn't host any fulltext index, thus, built an index locally, e.g. via Lucene, then get the data from the public endpoint afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your replies but I found by myself the solution actually :). See you !

Answer (score 2):

If you already now Scotland is [Entity Q22](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22) on wikidata,you can use the `https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Qxxxxx.json` URL to retrieve all the [statements](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Statements) related to Scotland, without using SQARQL: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q22.json.

See also: [About Data](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:About_data) in WikiData's help.

To search matching entities by a string, use the [wbsearchentities REST API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbsearchentities), for example: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=scotland&language=en .

Comment: Thank you Udi for your complete answer but I finally found myself the solution in my query, have a nice day :) !

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer and then accept it @Olscream?